# Django get_or_create only if form constraints are met

Tags: django, forms

I have a form that asks for a song's Artist, Title and Mix. Artist and Title are required fields but Mix is not. The form should only save if Artist, Title and Mix does not exists. If the form has either empty Artist or Title field it should show "This field is required" on submit.  The issue I'm having is if the Title field is empty but Artist is populated, it'll still create the Artist object with get_or_create (See ###forms.py below). How do I only create Artist object if the form is valid?

```
###########models.py
class Artist (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track (models.Model):    
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Artist")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Submitted by", default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Title")
    mix = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name="Mix")

###########views.py
class TrackCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, AjaxCreateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_message = "Thank you for submitting track: %(artist)s - %(title)s - %(mix)s"

    def get_initial(self):
        self.initial.update({ 'user': self.request.user })
        return self.initial

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(cleaned_data, 
            artist=self.object.artist, 
            title=self.object.title,
        )

###########forms.py
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = [
            "artist",
            "title",
            "mix",
            ]        
    artist = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength': '100',}))        

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs['initial']['user']
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Set layout for fields.
        my_field_text= [
            ('artist', 'Artist', ''),
            ('title', 'Title', ''),
            ('mix', 'Mix', ''),
        ]
        for x in my_field_text:
            self.fields[x[0]].label=x[1]
            self.fields[x[0]].help_text=x[2]

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('artist', css_class="col-sm-4"),
                Div('title', css_class="col-sm-4"),
                Div('mix', css_class="col-sm-4"),               
                css_class = 'row'
            ),
        )


    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(ProfileForm, self).save(False)
        obj.user = self.user
        commit and obj.save()
        return obj

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProfileForm, self).clean()

        artist = self.cleaned_data.get('artist')
        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
        mix = self.cleaned_data.get('mix')

        if artist and title:
            title = ' '.join([w.title() if w.islower() else w for w in title.split()])
            if mix:
                mix = ' '.join([w.title() if w.islower() else w for w in mix.split()])

            if Track.objects.filter(artist=artist, title=title, mix=mix).exists():
                msg = "Record with Artist and Title already exists."
                if mix:
                    msg = "Record with Artist, Title & Mix already exists."
                    self.add_error('mix', msg)
                self.add_error('artist', msg)
                self.add_error('title', msg)

        if not artist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Artist is a required field.")
        else:
            artist, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist)
            self.cleaned_data['artist'] = artist


        self.cleaned_data['title'] = title 
        self.cleaned_data['mix'] = mix
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Why do you have `get_or_create(name=artist)` in `clean_artist`, and not in the generic `clean`; only in the latter can you (as you do) check for `if artist and title`.

Comment: I removed clean_artist and now have it in generic clean.  Anyway to only get_or_create if form valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your comparison, by first checking if your form is valid in `clean()`?

```
def clean(self):
    ...
    if not artist:
        raise ValidationError("artist is a required field")
    if not title:
        raise ValidationError("title is a required field")
    ...
```

The above makes it a two-step process for the user, since if a user leaves both artist and title blank, they ony get the artist notice.
You could make a better (sub) if statement and a combined `ValidationError`, or solve that by using `clean_artist` and `clean_title`, just for raising the `ValidationError` (not using get_or_create in the field clean methods):

```
def clean_artist(self):
    # no get_or_create here
    ...
    if not artist:
        raise ValidationError("artist is a required field")

def clean_title(self):
    # no get_or_create here
    ...  
    if not title:
        raise ValidationError("title is a required field")

def clean(self):
    ...
    if title and artist:
        # get_or_create stuff here
    ...
```

This way, you should get both errors independently, but the get_or_create is still done in the main clean, only if title and artist are valid.